# Ubuntu Server 20.4.1 *-network DISABLED

Tags: networking

I had a working server this morning.  Wanted to apply the lastest set up updates, but before I did, I decided to do a reboot just to clean things up.

After the reboot.. then network did not come back.  I booted from a USB stick, and was able to access the network.  So I know it isn't the card or cable or external.

Here is the output from a lshw -C network:

```
  *-network DISABLED
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: eth1
   version: 04
   serial: 34:17:eb:a1:64:a1
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:27 memory:f7d00000-f7d1ffff memory:f7d39000-f7d39fff ioport:f080(size=32)


*-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: DGE-528T Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
       vendor: D-Link System Inc
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:01:02.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: c4:12:f5:33:9b:5f
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=32 link=no maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes
       resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7c20000-f7c200ff memory:f7c00000-f7c1ffff
```

And here is what I get from "ip a":

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:12:f5:33:9b:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:17:eb:a1:64:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

if I do a "ip  link set eth0 up" and "ip  link set eth1 up" and then do "ifconfig", it looks like I get an IPv6 address, but no IPV4.

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::c612:f5ff:fe33:9b5f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether c4:12:f5:33:9b:5f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 192  bytes 20095 (20.0 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 12  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 6  bytes 516 (516.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 34:17:eb:a1:64:a1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7d00000-f7d20000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 7768  bytes 551888 (551.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7768  bytes 551888 (551.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and here is my /etc/netplan/ file

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
```

Any ideas on what the heck happened (btw.. if I reboot, it goes back to both being disabled).

Comment: At GRUB, boot into your previous kernel. If it works properly in the previous kernel, then please file a proper bug report.

Comment: I do not get a GRUB boot option.  and I did not make any changes to the kernel.  Unless they got auto applied somehow. In fact, I had not manually applied any updates since the last reboot. :(

Comment: 1) Look up how to unhide GRUB. It's there. 2) Most upgrades for most folks get auto-applied. Review your /var/log/apt to see what has changed recently.

Comment: Thanks.  Yep.. bunch of stuff got auto applied.  Apparently one of them broke networking.

Comment: Something in this batch probably
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-modules-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64, automatic), linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64, automatic), linux-headers-5.4.0-58:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64, automatic), linux-headers-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.56.59, 5.4.0.58.61), linux-image-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.56.59, 5.4.0.58.61), linux-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.56.59, 5.4.0.58.61)
End-Date: 2020-12-13  06:55:29

Comment: I had this exact problem and it was caused by the "generally safe" (!!) `apt autoremove`. I pulled the removed packages by `grep remove /var/log/dpkg.log` and reinstalled most of them, save for `linux-headers*` and such. Rebooted the system and all was good. #Kubuntu2204 #DontTrustAutoremove

Answer (score 2):

Notice that your ethernet interfaces are eth0 and eth1; quite unusual for Ubuntu 20.04. Notice also that the netplan file attempts to configure the more usual enp1. Please change the netplan file to substitute eth0 for enp1. Next, do

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Check:

```
ip addr show
```

Any improvement?

Comment: Interesting.  I will need to try changing it to the ethx that I know the cable is plugged in to.

Comment: tried that.. during the reboot, the system hung. waiting for the network to come up.  It eventually did, but ip a didn't show anything different.  See my answer below.  Maybe that will help figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the .yaml file to the following:

network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
enp1:
dhcp4: true
match:
macaddress: c4:12:f5:33:9b:5f
set-name: enp1

which is the mac address of the interface I knew had the cable in it.
This worked. And after the reboot, I got my IPV4 address just fine.  Not sure what changed that it wouldn't find the interface that was connected the way it did a couple of weeks ago.